# Is it pythonic to reuse a feature of a dict, but not for dict-like features?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I would like to use the bracket expression used to access a value in a `dict`, but without any other `dict` features.

In the example below, I use the expression `variable[something]` to query `variable` in the same way as a `dict`. There are no other functionalities of a `dict` behind, what is returned is computed (it is either a color when `something` is `'color'`, or `"hello"` for anything else).

```
import random

class ColDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        dict.__init__(self, args)
        self.colors = ['blue', 'white', 'red']
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == 'color':
            random.shuffle(self.colors)
            return(self.colors[0])
        else:
            return("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    col = ColDict()
    print(col['color'], col['color'], col['something']) # red white hello (changes on each call)
```

This code works as expected.

What I would like to understand is **whether the reuse of a dict functionality (the bracket call) is pythonic, or at last acceptable.**

Note: I understand that this could be accomplished though other means (liek a function) but I am specifically instersted in reusing the brackets call. **Reusing, not misusing** (which is the core of my question)

Comment: I see no reason why you would want that class to derive from `dict`.  What's that buying you?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: the ability to use a bracket call.

Comment: This question is pretty much opinion-based. ***In my opinion.***

Comment: You're adding underscores around your method names just so you have to do `instance['attribute']` rather than `instance.attribute`. Doesn't look too Pythonic.

Comment: (Also, you're looking for `return random.choice(self.colors)`.)

Comment: @WoJ What gives you ability to use a bracket call is `__getitem__` function, not inheritance from `dict`. The only unpythonic thing is "explicit is better then implicit" (Zen of Python) so I suggest you simply create a method doing that. Immitating a dict will simply be confusing to others. But if for example you want to use your object as a replacement for dict somewhere else then this is completely fine.

Comment: @freakish: thank you - this is exactly the information i was missing. I was exactly in the situation you mentioned (thought that brackets are a feature of dict, not `__getitem__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need any functionality from dict, just provide `__getitem__()`

```
import random

class ColDict:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.colors = ['blue', 'white', 'red']
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == 'color':
            return random.choice(self.colors)
        else:
            return("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    col = ColDict()
    print(col['color'], col['color'], col['something']) # red white hello (changes on each call)
```

[read more about it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: And since OP is using Python 3, inheritance from `object` isn't necessary either.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is unpythonic. There's no need to inherit from a dictionary, as all you gain is slightly longer method names and attribute access syntax. Make an ordinary class with no explicit inheritance to return a random color. Since your class's `__getitem__` was returning a constant for every other value, make a class or instance variable with a constant that can be retrieved with a specific name instead of just "anything that isn't `color`." If you're worried about the user not being able to enter random attribute names to access that constant, remember that "There should be one – and preferably only one – obvious way to do it" (from [PEP-20, The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

```
import random

class ColObj:
    other = 'hello'
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.colors = ['blue', 'white', 'red']
    def color(self):
            return random.choice(self.colors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    col = ColObj()
    print(col.color, col.color, col.other)
```

If this is all the class does, I don't see much need for a class at all - you could simply define a function `color` and a string (or other constant) `other`.

```
import random

other = 'hello'
def color(colors=('blue', 'white', 'red')):
        return random.choice(colors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(color(), color(), other)
```

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation - the actual use case is more complicated, I just wrote a working example to base the question on.

Comment: @WoJ - I expected as much. I just wanted to emphasize that OOP should be used only when it adds value.

Comment: @WoJ: As TigerhawkT3 mentioned, you do not need a class here